# Updating mySQL data field via form not working

Tags: php, mysql, forms, updates

I'm trying to edit an item in a mySQL database generated list. Here is the code:

```
<?php
// contact to database
$connect = mysql_connect("<HOST>", "<USER>", "<PASSWORD>") or die ("Error , check your server connection.");
mysql_select_db("tvc");
?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE closet SET
    pattern = '{$_POST['pattern']}'
    WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'") or die ("Error in query");

// if successfully updated. 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='patterns.php'>Back to Patterns List</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

I get an 'error in query' error message and I can't figure out what is causing it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you don't look at the error message hints, you won't find out. Also there is a distinct lack of database escaping in your code. Work on that. (Or rather use PDO and prepared statements to avoid this cumbersome approach.)

Comment: Nice [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to remove `,` before `WHERE`

Change

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE closet SET
    pattern = '{$_POST['pattern']}',
    WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'") or die ("Error in query");
```

To

```
$pattern = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pattern']);
$id= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE closet SET
    pattern = '".$pattern."' WHERE id='".$id."'") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
```

Recommendations:

1.Learn to prevent from MySQL Injections: [Good Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

2.Mysql extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. More reading: [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: I just removed the , before WHERE and I still get the same error.

Comment: can you paste echo "UPDATE closet SET
    pattern = '{$_POST['pattern']}',
    WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'";

Comment: where in the file should I paste it?

Comment: I updated my PHP file w/ your edited code (starting from $result = and ending with mysql_error()); and I get the following error:

Comment: I figured it out! It had nothing to do with that php page but rather a value trying to be passed from the previous page. Thank you so much for revamping my code, though. Being able to see the error instead of a generic message helped me track it down.